# Remove all folders .old

Tags: powershell

I'm trying to delete all folders in `\\kiewitplaza\vdi\Appsense_profiles` that end with `.old`. The piece I have that says `Write-Host $name` is just me trying to test before I delete anything.

```psh
$name = Get-ChildItem "\\kiewitplaza\vdi\Appsense_profiles"
if ($name.name.EndsWith(".old")) {
    Write-Host $name
    #Remove-Item "\\kiewitplaza\vdi\Appsense_profiles\$name.old"
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Get-ChildItem` produces a list of objects. Use a pipeline for processing that list:

```psh
Get-ChildItem '\\kiewitplaza\vdi\Appsense_profiles' |
  Where-Object { $_.Name -like '*.old' } |
  Remove-Item
```

Comment: What does the ? after the | doing?

Comment: @user770022 Ah, sorry. That's an alias for `Where-Object`. Replaced.

Comment: Get-ChildItem \\kiewitplaza\vdi\Appsense_profiles | Where-Object {$_name -like '*.old'} | Out-GridView

I'm running this just to list out what it finds but its not displaying anything.

Comment: You changed his code. You need to use `-like` and not `-eq` in your `Where` statement.

Comment: Get-ChildItem '\\kiewitplaza\vdi\Appsense_profiles' -filter "*.old" | Out-GridView

This lists the .old folders.

Comment: @user770022 You are missing a period in what you pasted in the comment here. `$_name -like '*.old'` should be `$_.name -like '*.old'` Using a filter would be better anyway though. Use `Remove-Item -whatif` for testing